# string to a float do some math then back to a string

Tags: python, string, math

Okay i need to turn a string to a float do some math then back to a string

```
def item_price(data):       #grabs price of item
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
    info = soup.find('span', itemprop='price').text
    info = info.replace("$","")
    info = float(info);         #  but evary thing below this line goes wrong 
    info = info * .2 + info
    info = "$" + string(info);
    return(info);
```

Comment: `but evary thing below this line goes wrong` -> What goes wrong?

Comment: try `str(info)` instead of `string(info)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't know anything about BeautifulSoap, but I think it's the semicolons.  Try this and see if it works:

```
from decimal import *

def item_price(data):       
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
    info = soup.find('span', itemprop='price').text
    info = info.replace("$","")
    info = Decimal(info)
    info = (info * Decimal(0.2)) + info
    return '${0:.2f}'.format(info)
```

Note: you had some other obvious syntax problems that I tried to clean up. Also, note that you should probably use decimal (over float) for money.

[Link to Decimal docs](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html)